# Server can't find gems after switching to rbenv from RVM

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I have an app that was created when I used RVM. I switched to rbenv and can't get it to work. When I try to run the server, it says it can't find the formastic gem:

```
Could not find formtastic-2.2.1 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
```

If I run `bundle install`, it says my bundle is complete, but formtastic is not listed.

However, `bundle show formtastic` shows that it's installed:

```
bundle show formtastic
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/formtastic-2.2.1
```

but the server can't find it:

```
Macintosh-2:$ rails s
Could not find formtastic-2.2.1 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
```

Comment: Most likely the server is using the ruby from .rvm. How do you start the server? What happens if you rename the .rvm directory?

Comment: @DiegoBasch I did rvm implode to remove rvm. I thought that was supposed to remove rvm.  I normally start the server 'rails s'

Answer (score 1):

In addition to running the command `rvm implode` to remove RVM, I also had to remove the .rvm directory from the home directory, as the system seemed to be looking in there for gems:

```
rm -rf .rvm
```

Once I removed that, I was able to start the server.